# How to do signaling in WebRTC without using WebSocket or http or mail

Tags: webrtc, p2p, sdp, rtcdatachannel, signaling

As far as I search, All WebRTC handshakes are done through any signaling server [ HTTP, WebSocket, etc..] even through Mail or Whatsapp.
But I expect to connect without using any of them. Is there any way to archive this?

If yes, please give me a brief solution. ThankYou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebRTC (as implemented in browsers) requires signalling. You can choose a different medium for signalling such as a piece of paper or calling someone on the phone, but it needs signalling.

If you want to be able to initiate unsolicited connections you need to use TCP or UDP directly which (if we ignore NAT and firewalls) don't have that restriction.